# Is there a way to view GIS data in Google Glass?

Tags: gis, kml, google-glass

I expected that it would be fairly straightforward to view KML or GML files in Google Glass, but I'm not really seeing the option with existing apps.

Comment: This has to do with programming how?  Off-topic, voted to close.

Comment: In that I'll have to do some programming if no one else has!  I'm just surprised to not find it already written. If it should go somewhere else, I'm happy to move it.

Comment: See [Google Glass Area 51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52492/google-glass), [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53059/what-gis-applications-use-google-glass), and for the full list, Google `"google glass" site:stackexchange.com`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it doesn't seem that the Glass GDK or Mirror API have built-in support for KML or GML.  Not sure this helps, but you could potentially render your KML to an image format (PNG, i.e.) using something like [mapnik](http://mapnik.org/faq/) (which has  Python bindings for example) on your server and deliver the resulting PNG to your timeline as a card. Not a very interactive but may help.

Comment: cool.  I haven't seen mapnik before.  at least good for a start.